# form1 doesn't close when clicked on X

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I got a tiny little problem.. I needed to stop it in Visual Studio
**UPDATE:**

`Form1` does not close anymore..

in my `Form1`, I have a code in where I create instances of `Form2` - `Dim f as New Fomr2` but when I press its ***X*** button, it closes and I am not able to call it again, coz its `disposed` so to handle that. I made this code..

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

but after adding the above code, something magical happened..

**I can't close `Form1`**

I already did `Application.Exit()` and `Me.Close` on `Form1_FormClosing` event and it does not Fire. this is very irritating for me. lol

Comment: maybe Me refer to form1.and it just hides.change to Form2.FormClosing and post detailed code

Comment: that code is from `form2` so `Me` is `form2` and even if it refers to my mainform, it should Hide right? but nothing is happening.. :/

Comment: Are you sure that it is being held from closing by this code? Could you out comment and try?

Comment: e.Cancel = True does prevent Form2 from closing. Could you please point out the roles of Form1 vs Form2 in your application?

Comment: yup. I already did.. I added that code, because I always close form2 and I cannot call it back, so I did that. then the next thing, I can't close form1. so I reverted my recent change, commented it out. and then X works well.

Comment: @fan711 yep, it does not close anymore, but one thing is, form1 does not close and neither hide too.

Comment: Is there a Form1_FormClosing or any relevant code in Form1?

Comment: if you posted some more code we would know what was the exact problem.

Comment: @fan711 well, since I wasn't able to close it using X, I added a formclosing event on my form1, does not work too.

Comment: @AdorableVB if code is small post whole code

Comment: updated it. and that the only code in `Form2` when I added that code, this problem is killing me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set closable to false

```
Public Class Form2
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Public Property closable As Boolean

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClosing(ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
        If closable = True Then 
            MyBase.OnClosing(e)
            Return 
        End If
        e.Cancel = True
        Me.Hide() 
    End Sub

End Class
```

For Usage you can use this way Whenever you want your form2 to appear just call it:

```
'inside your form1
Public  Sub  ShowForm2()
    Static f As New Form2
    f.closable = False 'it cant be true otherwise you will get exception on next call
    f.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: okay, this worked. :) lesson learned "Don't use that code anymore" lol

Answer (score 0):

How did you call your form2?

And Remove the **e.Cancel = True** or **change it to false**.
If the Cancel is set to true you are telling the VB.net to cancel the forms closing..

Comment: `dim f as new form2` so that when I close it, I can open it again. that's why I added that. but, that code should only work on `form2` then why is it affecting my mainform

Comment: Have you called Form2 as Dialog?

Comment: I think your problem is form two is not disposed that is why when you close form1, form1 1 will try to close/dispose form2 but your suppressing the disposal of form2 in your form2 closing event. try adding switch and property and set it when you want to by cancel.

Comment: I do get you, but I don't know what to use. can you update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

here is the seleton

```
form1 ...

    dim f2 as form2 = new form2
    private sub showButton()
        f2.shwo()
    end sub

    private sub DisposeF2()
        f2.ForceCLose = true
    end sub

end...

form2....
    public ForceCLose as boolean = false

    Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
                    if not ForceClose then  
            e.Cancel = True
            Me.Hide()
    end if
    End Sub
end...
```